# Python print nth element from list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
[[50.954818803035948, 55.49664787231189, 8007927.0, 0.0], 
[50.630482185654436, 55.133473852776916, 8547795.0, 0.0],
[51.32738085400576, 55.118344981379266, 6600841.0, 0.0], 
[49.425931642638567, 55.312890225131163, 7400096.0, 0.0], 
[48.593467836476407, 55.073137270550006, 6001334.0, 0.0]]
```

I want to print the third element from every list. The desired result is:

```
8007927.0
8547795.0
6600841.0
7400096.0
6001334.0
```

I tried:

```
print data[:][2]
```

but it is not outputting the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many way to do this. Here's a simple list way, without an explicit `for` loop.

```
tt = [[50.954818803035948, 55.49664787231189, 8007927.0, 0.0], [50.630482185654436, 55.133473852776916, 8547795.0, 0.0], [51.32738085400576, 55.118344981379266, 6600841.0, 0.0], [49.425931642638567, 55.312890225131163, 7400096.0, 0.0], [48.593467836476407, 55.073137270550006, 6001334.0, 0.0]]

print [x[2] for x in tt]

> [8007927.0, 8547795.0, 6600841.0, 7400096.0, 6001334.0]
```

And making is safe for potentially shorted lists

```
print [x[2] for x in tt if len(tt) > 3]
```

More sophisticated output (python 2.7), prints values as newline (\n) seperated

```
print '\n'.join([str(x[2]) for x in tt])

> 8007927.0
> 8547795.0
> 6600841.0
> 7400096.0
> 6001334.0
```

Comment: As stated in [answer], please avoid answering unclear, overly-broad, typo, opinion-based, unreproducible, or duplicate questions. Write-my-code requests and low-effort homework questions are off-topic for [so] and more suited to professional coding/tutoring services. Good questions adhere to [ask], include a [mcve], have research effort, and have the potential to be useful to future visitors. Answering inappropriate questions harms the site by making it more difficult to navigate and encouraging further such questions, which can drive away other users who volunteer their time and expertise.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for item in data:
    if len(item) >= 3: # to prevent list out of bound exception.
        print(int(item[2]))
```

Comment: You will need to do `int(item[2])`.

Comment: @AKS Edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you try a map function
In python 3:

```
 list(map(lambda l: l[2], z))
```

In python 2:

```
map(lambda l: l[2], z)
```

Answer (score 3):

`map` and `list comprehensive` have been given, I would like to provide two more ways, say `d` is your list:

With `zip`:

```
zip(*d)[2]
```

With `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> nd = numpy.array(d)
>>> print(nd[:,2])
[ 8007927.,  8547795.,  6600841.,  7400096.,  6001334.]
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to print the `n`th element of every list from a list of lists, you need to first access each list, and then access the `n`th element in that list.

In practice, it would look something like this

```
def print_nth_element(listset, n):
   for listitem in listset:
      print(int(listitem[n])) # Since you want them to be ints
```

Which could then be called in the form `print_nth_element(data, 2)` for your case.

The reason your `data[:][2]` is not yielding correct results is because `data[:]` returns the entire list of lists as it is, and then executing getting the 3rd element of that same list is just getting the thirst element of the original list. So `data[:][2]` is practically equivalent to `data[2]`.